# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flip is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure why this works locally but doesn't work on a server.

My call on my index page goes jQuery, then this plugin, then the rest of my JS.

It doesn't execute my function though and I'm not sure why. Can someone explain why it's showing this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flip is not a function

Here is my function:

```
    var callFlip = function() {
    var $card = $('.card').flip({
        axis: 'y',
        trigger: 'hover'
    });
};
```

Comment: And did you include he flip plugin on the page?

Comment: *"why it's saying 'is not a function'"* What's the actual error message though?

Comment: The error is in the title

Comment: I think we need to see the script tags so we can make sure that they are loading correctly.

Comment: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="bower_components/flip/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="components/tiles/tiles.js"></script>`

Comment: Those relative URIs might not be correct. You may want to change them to absolute URLs. Also, check the console for errors loading the script files.

Comment: Look at the console and the network.resources tab[s] do you see the JS file loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Most certain that you are not including the JS file where the `$.flip` function gets defined to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Either your scripts are not loaded or you may have conflicts b/w jQuery and flip plugin in terms of versions. Make sure you have the latest version of jQuery and flip plugin included. Here is a working demo:

```js
$("#card").flip({
    axis: 'y',
    trigger: 'hover'
});
```

```css
#card > div {
    height: 150px !important;
    width: 200px !Important;
}
.front {
    background-color: green;
}
.back {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/asset/js/jquery.flip.js"></script>
<div id="card"> 
  <div class="front"></div> 
  <div class="back"></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the "flip.js" file has been loaded to the browser or not. The "TypeError" triggers when you are calling a function or element of the DOM which doesn't exist.

May be the "src" path given to load the "flip.js" file is wrong. 
You can download the filp.js file from here http://nnattawat.github.io/flip/ and upload the js file to your server and load it after the jQuery file.

Answer (score 0):

Well folks, you were all super helpful! The problem was being caused by Grunt's compiling of my JS files. It wasn't grabbing that flip.js file. So there we go.

Thanks for answering me!