# flip js plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/ but keep getting

> $(...).flip is not a function

I've already checked [Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flip is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029478/uncaught-typeerror-flip-is-not-a-function) this question.
I load flip.js from cdn.

Here I include the plugin

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.js"></script>
```

Here I call the function.

```
   btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var flips = '#' + flipArr[i].id;
        $(flips).flip();
    });
```

Here flip.js is loaded to the browser

[image: flip.js is loaded in the browser]

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery? And in correct order?

Comment: Yes, i've loaded jquery, not sure about order. What should it be?

Comment: Load jQuery first and then flip. Also, if you are already using jQuery, why use `btn.addEventListener`?

Comment: Yes jquery loaded first. But may be some issues with jquery version? I'm not very familiar with kquery and js at all, so sometimes I'm confused with it.